# 'IPromise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm building a confirm dialog for when the user changes tabs. The code works fine but *tslint* complains about a type mismatch. The controller looks like:

```
export class MyController implements ng.IController {

    constructor(private $transitions: TransitionService,
                private $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService) {
        'ngInject';

        $transitions.onStart({}, () =>
            this.alert
                .showConfirm(
                    this.$translate.instant('dialogs.confirmLeave.content'),
                    this.$translate.instant('dialogs.confirmLeave.title')
                )
                .then(() => true)
                .catch(() => false)
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

`this.alert.showConfirm` eventually calls `this.$uibModal.open()` from angular-ui-bootstrap. This gives the following warning:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '() => IPromise<boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransitionHookFn'.
  Type 'IPromise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | void | TargetState | Promise<boolean | void | TargetState>'.
    Type 'IPromise<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<boolean | void | TargetState>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '{ <TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: boolean) => TResult | IPromise<TResult>, errorCallbac...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = boolean | void | TargetState, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: boolean | void ...'.
          Type 'IPromise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
            Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
              Type '{ <TResult>(successCallback: (promiseValue: any) => TResult | IPromise<TResult>, errorCallback?: ...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = any, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: (value: any) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>...'.
                Type 'IPromise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like whatever `this.alert.showConfirm()` is, it isn't returning a real `Promise`. Try wrapping the result in a `Promise`:

```
export class MyController implements ng.IController {

    constructor(private $transitions: TransitionService,
                private $translate: angular.translate.ITranslateService) {
        'ngInject';

        $transitions.onStart({}, () =>
            Promise.resolve(
                this.alert
                    .showConfirm(
                        this.$translate.instant('einsteinsst.dialogs.confirmLeave.content'),
                        this.$translate.instant('einsteinsst.dialogs.confirmLeave.title')
                    )
            )
            .then(() => true)
            .catch(() => false)
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

`Promise.resolve()` will convert any thenable (i.e. anything that implements `IPromise` into a genuine `Promise`, but the `IPromise` interface isn't directly compatible with `Promise`.
See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) for further details.

Comment: thanks for the insight, it works. An alternate, more verbose way to go about it is to replace `Promise.resolve` with this form: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {// some logic; return resolve(value) })`